# Spark Cassandra NoClassDefFoundError guava/cache/CacheLoader

Tags: java-8, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-spark-2.0

Running Cassandra 2.2.8, Win7, JDK8, Spark2, HAve thse in the CP: Cassandra core 3.12, spark-cassandra-2.11, Spark-cassandra-java-2.11, Spark2.11, spark-network-common_2.11, Guava-16.0.jar, sacala2.11.jar, etc 
Trying to run a basic example- **compiles fine**, but when when I try to run-  at the first line itself get error:
`SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader`

Missing **spark-network-common** is supposed to cause this error - but I do have it. Any conflicting jars?
Thanks

Comment: Check spark class path, are you running with assembly jar or submitting jar runtime?

Comment: @uttam - no I was not using assembly jar and was not submitting jar at runtime. The issue was finally resolved by using the maven pom - I guess some conflicting/missing jars. The pom added several dozen jars- so however the magic happened.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is: don't exactly know the answer but the problem was solved. Used the the pom and created a maven project in eclipse. it brought in several (dozen) jars and it finally worked. So likely some conflicting/missing jar - tried to look into it- hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the repository. To check the whether jar with the lastupdated .If it has lastupdated, and then del those files. And download again.