# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader when running Spark example from Master/Sources in Intellij

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

When running an example  - LDA `OneVsRestExample` in this case - there are a couple of issues that arise.

First: the `provided` dependencies need to be changed to `compile`. That was done.

```
<hadoop.deps.scope>compile</hadoop.deps.scope>
<hive.deps.scope>compile</hive.deps.scope>
<parquet.deps.scope>compile</parquet.deps.scope>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spark-project.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>unused</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>

 ..etc
```

Then the following more difficult to diagnose issue surfaces:

```
objc[85400]:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:918)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.ml.OneVsRestExample$.main(OneVsRestExample.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.ml.OneVsRestExample.main(OneVsRestExample.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have seen another post about this [Spark Cassandra NoClassDefFoundError guava/cache/CacheLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983971/spark-cassandra-noclassdeffounderror-guava-cache-cacheloader).  But the answer was basically a non-answer - "It started to work but I'm not sure why". So this question is an attempt to get to the bottom of this issue more systematically.

The error is clearly a missing dependency. But a full `mvn package` has already been performed on the entire distribution - which is spark Master for `2.3.0-SNAPSHOT`. In addition the `reimport maven project` was performed in IJ.

So the intention of this question is to examine: what other "knobs" affect the maven dependencies - and thus might be turned to attempt to resolve the missing classes issue?

**Update** There is apparently some ***complex*** gymnastics happening in the `spark-core` codebase to deal specifically with `guava shading` : here are some attempts to deal with it:

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2876

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3658

It is not clear whether `examples` actually presently *work* within Intellij. Further tips (likely from seasoned spark source developers) would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Specifically, I am interested of running  history-server locally

Comment: Long time ago - i think not or I would have provded an answer directly